# How to apply a macro/vba formula to more than just one cell

Tags: vba, macros

I have entered the follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$V$2" Then
    Range("U2") = Range("V2") * Range("O2")
End If

If Target.Address = "$U$2" Then
    Range("V2") = Range("U2") / Range("O2")
End If

End Sub
```

.....However, this only works on cells u2 and v2. I need this formula to run all the way down column U and column V.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? At the moment it looks like you specify a single cell, and it applies to a single cell? Can you update your question with what your macro is trying to achieve?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do:   Column O contains salary information, column U would be the dollar amount that a manager would want to increase the salary by.  Column V would be the percentage that the salary may be increased by.  Some managers prefer enter a dollar amount and the % automatically updating.  Other managers want to enter a percentage and have the dollar amount in column U automatically populate.  the formula I entered accomplishes that, but for row 2 only.  Does this help?

Comment: And when do you want this to happen? At the moment you've applied this to the `Worksheet_Change` event, did you want it to fire every time you change a cell?

Comment: Yes, I want it to happen each time someone enters a value in either columns

Comment: A couple of answers below that hopefully will help you then :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you could use something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Don't apply to column headers
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Make changes to anything in Column V (22)
    If Target.Column = 22 Then
        If IsNumeric(Range("V" & Target.Row)) And IsNumeric(Range("O" & Target.Row)) Then
            Range("U" & Target.Row) = Range("V" & Target.Row) * Range("O" & Target.Row)
        End If
    End If

    'Make changes to anything in Column U (21)
    If Target.Column = 21 Then
        If IsNumeric(Range("U" & Target.Row)) And IsNumeric(Range("O" & Target.Row)) And Range("O" & Target.Row) <> 0 Then
            Range("V" & Target.Row) = Range("U" & Target.Row) / Range("O" & Target.Row)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This event fires every time a cell is changed. As such, it will check which column the change is in - `If Target.Column = 22 Then`... If the column is 22 (Numerical representation for column `V`) it will progress to the rest of the code, which is to change U, V and O using the `Target.Row`, that is, the row number of the changed cell.

Edit: Added the Divide By Zero checking, and checking to make sure all entered items are in fact numbers and not letters/symbols.

Comment: Nice error checking!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Intersect(Target, Range("U:V")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V:V")) Is Nothing Then
         Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value / Range("O" & Target.Row).Value
      Else
         Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value / Range("O" & Target.Row).Value
      End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Note:**  This excludes the first row.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would mention that setting `Application.EnableEvents = False` could be slightly dangerous in that, if the debugger throws an error before being set back to true, you'd need to manually run another macro to re-enable events.

Comment: @Jonno  I need to avoid re-triggering the *Event.*

Comment: Strangely my code doesn't seem to re-trigger itself. Not sure why, as you say, it seems that it should do. I'll leave mine as it is as it seems to work for me, but if you are using that, consider adding something like `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` with an `ErrHandler: Application.EnableEvents = True` right at the end. Otherwise, test your code currently and enter a letter in one of those fields, I'm fairly sure it'll stop you triggering an event ever again.

Comment: Looking it up further, [this result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) states: `Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed --by the user-- or by an external link.`. I'm suspicious VBA calls don't trigger the event again, to prevent infinite loops.